# Не могу создать глобальную переменную типа string

Tags: c++, linux

Пытаюсь создать 3 глобальных переменных типа string, но компилятор пишет, что не указан тип переменной, то есть он ее просто не видит

> error: ‘String’ does not name a type
>    String s3 = "";

```
#include <sys/types.h>  
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <arpa/inet.h>   
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <functional> 

int count = 0;
string s1 = "";
string s2 = "";
string s3 = "";


using namespace std;
```

Comment: Сообщение об ошибке не имеет отношение к представленному вами коду, так как нигде в вашем коде нет объявления String s3 = ""; Что касается представленного вами кода, то директива using namespace std; должна предшествовать объявления переменных s1, s2 и s3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Или используйте имя типа `std::string`, или добавьте строку

```
using std::string;
```

или

```
using namespace std;
```

Тип `string` находится в пространстве имен `std`.

Само собой, эти строки должны находиться **ДО** использования типа `string`.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace

Answer (score 2):

Данное сообщение об ошибке

> error: ‘String’ does not name a type String s3 = "";

не имеет отношение к представленному вами коду, так как нигде в коде не встречается объявление

```
String s3 = "";
```

Что касается представленного кода, то вам следует поместить директиву

```
using namespace std;
```

перед объявлениями переменных `s1`, `s2` и `s3`. То есть этот фрагмент кода

```
string s1 = "";
string s2 = "";
string s3 = "";


using namespace std;
```

перепишите по крайней мере как

```
using namespace std;

string s1 = "";
string s2 = "";
string s3 = "";
```

Иначе имя `string` будет не объявленным, так как его объявление находится не в глобальном пространстве имен, а в стандартном пространстве имен `std`.

И нет никакой необходимости инициализировать объекты типа `std::string` пустой строкой. Так что вы можете написать просто.

```
using namespace std;

string s1;
string s2;
string s3;
```

Естественно было бы лучше не вносить все имена из стандартного пространства имен в глобальное пространство имен с помощью директивы `using namespace std;`, а использовать квалифицированные имена, что позволит избежать потенциальной неоднозначности имен. Например,

```
// remove this directive
// using namespace std;

std::string s1;
std::string s2;
std::string s3;
```

Также стандартные C заголовки

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

следует объявлять как

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
```